Show daily quotes in vb.net app from zenquotes.io
I want to show the random Quotes from zenquotes.io with the help of API.
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Try
        Label4.Text = GetQuotes().ToString
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Public Async Function GetQuotes() As Task(Of String)
    Using client = New HttpClient()
        Dim response = Await client.GetAsync("https://zenquotes.io/api/random")
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
        Dim content As String = Await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
        Return content
    End Using
End Function

However, this shows the text System.Threading.Tasks.Task``1[System.String] in the label instead of a quote.
How can I fix it?

it is showing "System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.String]" in label text but not showing Quotes

The GetQuotes() function doesn't directly return a string you can use to set the label. It's an async function returning a Task that can be converted to a string. What you are seeing is the result of calling the ToString() method on this Task object. You have to await or otherwise process that Task before you can get the string you want.
Ideally, I'd use the Await option, but that would require you to also mark the event handler method as Async, and I don't have a lot of practice yet doing that for WinForms events. So instead I'll suggest this:
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Try
        Dim t As Task(Of String) = GetQuotes()
        t.GetAwaiter().GetResult()
        Label4.Text = t.Result
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub


Again: this isn't really how async operations are normally done, and maybe you should just mark the Button_Click method as Aysnc so you can await the task:
Private Async Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Try
        Label4.Text = Await GetQuotes()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

But I don't have personal experience doing it this way in Windows forms, for whether there might be odd side effects having an Async event handler on forms control.
